# Implode in query breaking code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, mysqli

I am working on building private message capability and the tutorial I am watching is based in mysql, so I am converting over to mysqli and avoiding creating an extra class for the following function the demonstrator created inside of it, so I am housing it in the same page.

I am receiving the follow error on my query

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in

My query is this...

```
$stmt = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `id`, `username` FROM users WHERE username IN ('" . implode("', '", $user_names) . "')")
```

What am I doing wrong in my query to make this error come up? It is spot on what the demonstrator had. Could putting my function on the same page be the cause of this? Basically what he is trying to do is allow different users to be added in the 'To:' line so that it can be comma separated like.

Bob, Tim, George, etc

Full Code

```
function fetch_user_ids($user_names){
    foreach ($user_names as &$name){
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($name);
    }
}
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
$stmt = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `id`, `username` FROM users WHERE username IN ('" . implode("', '", $user_names) . "')")
//$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `id`, `username` FROM users WHERE username IN ('" . implode("', '", $user_names) . "')")
    or die ("Messages query failed: %s\n".($stmt->error));
//$stmt->execute();
//$stmt->bind_result($message_id, $message_username);

$names = array();

while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) !== false) {
    $names[$row['username']] = $row['id'];
}
return $names;
```

Comment: I suspect your implode is maybe messing up the string, but I'm not at home to test it out right now, maybe try messing with it to create your variable outside of your select, then use a parameterized select statement with the new variable.

Comment: I have no idea how I could do that.

Comment: This should get you started:

$implodedUsers = implode("', '", $user_names);

var_dump($implodedUsers);

That will let you see what the string actually looks like, I just suspect there's a rogue comma or something maybe.

Comment: Did you set `$user_names` anywhere? That fetch_ function isn't called, or is it? -- And really, you should use an existing `IN` list building function (perhaps even one that uses proper parameter binding), instead of mashing in that `implode` workaround manually.

Comment: @BryantFrankford It comes up NULL

Comment: Is your $user_names variable getting set correctly?

Comment: It appears it isn't. In the video I watched. I do not know where he set the $user_names variable. I will have to look tonight and update this. Do you think that could be why this is failing?

Comment: @Paul That's definitely why it's failing. `implode()` requires the second argument to be an array, and you're not setting `$user_names` to an array.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check out the video tonight and see if I was missing something and if not update this question.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get means that you do not pass a valid array.

**Be sure that $user_names is an array with one dimension, such as:**

```
$user_names = ['Rob','Joe','Dan'];
```

Secondly, you've a strange/difficult function fetch_user_ids(). Replace that function with a simple native php function:

```
$user_names = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $user_names);
```

If the input $user_names is an array, the output is a sanatized array, so you can use the implode exactly as in your example query.